# Image control not showing the image when run code

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

Quick summary - i add image control on simple wpf window and set image .while design time it shows and but in run time its doesn't and not showing any exception

`<Grid>
 <Image Name ="im1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="127,147,0,0"VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/chetas logo.bmp"  />
 </Grid>'`

Comment: Have you set the `Copy to Output Directory` property of the *chetas logo.bmp* file to `Copy Always` or `Copy if Newer`?

Comment: Ya i set that property as copy always but it doesn't work result is same

Comment: Thanks Anders Gustafsson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it .. when i set my image build in action property as embedded resource